# What is the fastest way to overwrite an entire file with zeros in C?

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, file-io

What I need to do is to fill the entire file contents with zeros in the fastest way. I know some linux commands like `cp` actually gets what is the best block size information to write at a time, but I wasn't able to figure out if using this block size information is enough to have a nice performance and looks like the `st_blksize` from the `stat()` isn't giving me that block size.
Thank you !

Some answers to the comments:

1. This need to be done in C, not using utilities like shred.
2. There is no error in the usage of the `stat()`
3. `st_blksize` is returning a block greater than the file size,
   don't know how can I handle that.
4. Using truncate()/ftruncate(), only the extra space is filled with
   zeros, I need to overwrite the **entire** file data.

I'm thinking in something like:

```
fd = open("file.txt", O_WRONLY);
// check for errors (...)
while(TRUE)
{
    ret = write(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (ret == -1) break;
}
close(fd);
```

The problem is how to define the best buffer size "programmatically".

Comment: How about just invoking `shred -n0 -z _filename_`?

Comment: What makes you say that stat st_blksize isn't returning the number you seek?  Odds are you should post the code because there is likely a bug in your usage of stat(2).

Comment: How about [ftruncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate)? Truncate to 0 and then expand to desired size.

Comment: See the answers in the updated description.

Comment: Oh sorry Banthar, now I understood your truncate(fd,0) and truncate(fd, size), saw it now in R.. answer and figured out, but this isn't going to lose too much performance ?

Comment: Why would it lose performance?

Comment: I don't know, but truncating to zero and then truncating to the entire size again seems like it is going to reallocate the entire size again, but it's just a guess, I really don't know the inner operations behind this.

Comment: Reallocating all-zero blocks is a lot less expensive than overwriting non-zero blocks with zeros... especially if they're all virtual (sparse) until actually written-to.

Comment: The ftruncate() method is likely to use "holes" - sparse files, if the filesystem supports it; this is going to be very efficient. It won't overwrite any data blocks though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fastest and simplest:

```
int fd = open("file", O_WRONLY);
off_t size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
ftruncate(fd, 0);
ftruncate(fd, size);
```

Obviously it would be nice to add some error checking.

This solution is **not** what you want for secure obliteration of the file though. It will simply mark the old blocks used by the file as unused and leave a sparse file that doesn't occupy any physical space. If you want to clear the old contents of the file from the physical storage medium, you might try something like:

```
static const char zeros[4096];
int fd = open("file", O_WRONLY);
off_t size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
while (size>sizeof zeros)
    size -= write(fd, zeros, sizeof zeros);
while (size)
    size -= write(fd, zeros, size);
```

You could increase the size of `zeros` up to 32768 or so if testing shows that it improves performance, but beyond a certain point it should not help and will just be a waste.

Comment: ftruncate(fd, 0) and then ftruncate(fd, size) will not lose too much performance ?

Comment: @Tarantula: This is about as fast as it gets.

Comment: It should use virtually no time at all, since all it does it adjust some filesystem metadata...

Comment: @R: The second approach is not guaranteed to work for "secure delete". In particular, it will not work for a COW filesystem such as BTRFS or ZFS.

Comment: Indeed, I should have mentioned that. Still, the second approach may be preferable if you want it to be closer to fail-safe (it will succeed even if the device is full, except with weird COW semantics, and will not leave a sparse file to which writes could later fail due to insufficient storage space).

Comment: @R: Good point, although arguably posix_fallocate() should be a more performant alternative to the "guaranteed space" issue.

Comment: Some question: changing the lseek (seek_end) to stat() in order to get size will probably be better ? The 'static const char' is always guaranteed to be zero ?

Comment: @Tarantula - For the first question, I don't know. Test both and see which one is faster. For the second, yes. Global variables and `static` local variables are always initialized to `0` unless given explicit initialization. It's only automatic (static) variables that have garbage values if left uninitialized.

Comment: Why would you prefer `stat` to `lseek`? My experience is that `stat` always has more of a chance of being a performance cost, and it's less likely to work for getting the size - it won't fail in your situation, but it will fail to report size for block devices, whereas `lseek` will get the size correctly. Unfortunately there's an erroneous and (IMO) harmful CERT paper that advises against using seek-to-end for getting file sizes, which has lots of folks confused about these issues...

Comment: @janneb: About `posix_fallocate`, the problem is a race condition. If you truncate the file length to 0 then use `posix_fallocate`, there's a window where you might "lose" the space you already had allocated if another file is created between the two calls. Overwriting the data already there does not have this issue.

Comment: ...unless the FS is based on COW and some blocks are shared, but then you've basically identified a situation equivalent to overcommit. I don't know if ZFS and BTRFS have concepts like commit charge and overcommit protection, but if they aim to be usable on high-reliability production systems, they damn well should....

Answer (score 4):

With mmap (and without error checking):

```
stat(filename,&stat_buf);
len=stat_buf.st_size;
fd=open(filename,O_RDWR);
ptr=mmap(NULL,len,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
memset(ptr,0,len);
munmap(ptr,len);
close(fd);
```

This should use the kernel's idea of block size, so you don't need to worry about it.  Unless the file is larger than your address space.

Answer (score -1):

This is my idea; notice I removed every error checking code for clarity.

```
int f = open("file", "w");             // open file
int len = lseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);       // and get its length
lseek(f, 0, SEEK_BEG);                 // then go back at the beginning
char *buff = malloc(len);              // create a buffer large enough
memset(buff, 0, len);                  // fill it with 0s
write(f, buff, len);                   // write back to file
close(f);                              // and close
```

Comment: Seems horribly dangerous since the chances of the file being too large for malloc are quite great.

Comment: You could do this same thing a lot cleaner and more efficiently using mmap

Comment: Also, I doubt any solution using `malloc` will be the fastest. The optimal solution shouldn't use O(n) memory overhead.

Comment: That, and `write()` isn't guaranteed to write out the whole file at once.

Comment: You could use a single moderately large buffer (maybe 32k) and `writev` with an `iov` array that points the the same zero buffer over and over again. That should give better cache coherency and avoid entering kernelspace multiple times.