# Zero'ing out a file

Tags: c, file-io

What is the most efficient quickest way to write all zeros to a file? including error checking. Would it just be fwrite? or is fseek involved?

I've looked elsewhere and saw code similar to this:

```
off_t size = fseek(pFile,0,SEEK_END);
fseek(pFile,0,SEEK_SET);

while (size>sizeof zeros)  
    size -= fwrite(&address, 1, sizeof zeros, pFile); 
while (size)    
    size -= fwrite(&address, 1, size, pFile);
```

where zeros is an array of file size I suspect. Not sure exactly what off_t was because it wasn't directly intuitive to me anyways

Comment: `off_t` is a type, for example could be `unsigned int` used to represent offsets. The code looks pretty good in fact.

Comment: could you give me a quick run through on what the for for loop is doing? That's the only part that I'm having semi trouble understanding... to me it looks like size - fwrite(&address, 1, sizeof zeros, pFile) is stored into size or something

Comment: [ftruncate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392110/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-overwrite-an-entire-file-with-zeros-in-c)

Comment: Will ftruncate(fd, 0) and then ftruncate(fd, size) which is mentioned there be the fastest way to go?

Comment: Do you need to be sure of erasing the bits actually on the disk, or is it enough to render them inaccessible via the normal filesystem API?

Comment: erase the bits I believe. I want to basically "clear" it out to be used again when I need to. It needs to be filled with all zeros

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Let me try it another way: If someone dismounts your file system and uses a forensic utility to inspect the raw contents of the hard drive, and they find the bits that were in the file before you overwrote them with zeroes, *would that be bad?*

Comment: Actually, I have another question: What would go wrong if you simply used [`remove`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) to delete this file?

Comment: @ Zack, Sorry for the confusing Zack. I should have prefaced saying this is function is part to simulate read writing to memory. The writing reading clearing the file is just to physically show i'm doing it. The above @address is what i mean when i say i'm going to be reading writing clearing parts of memory for a simulation

Comment: No. That leaves no record for future people with the same problem.  The chat rooms are a misfeature.   Anyway, if what you're doing is simulating memory, you want the `write` approach, not the `ftruncate` approach.  `ftruncate` would be cheating since it's O(1) rather than O(N).

Comment: ok. I agree with that. basically I want to write to a file. clear it out and initialize it to 0 and then write to the file again. That's the "type" of functionality I want to produce. whatever was there clear it out and make it all zeros

Comment: @Questioneer, the `while` loops are for this: You are trying to write `sizeof zeros` bytes, by saying `fwrite(..., sizeof zeros, ...)`, BUT, `fwrite` may actually write fewer bytes (because `sizeof zeros` is too big), so in a while loop, you keep trying to write as much as you can, and keep track of how much was actually written. If all you wanted to write was not completed yet, you retry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to replace the *contents* of the file with a stream of binary zeroes of the same length, or do you want to simply *empty* the file? (make it have length zero)

Either way, this is best done with the OS file I/O primitives.  Option one:

```
char buf[4096];
struct stat st;
int fd;
off_t pos;
ssize_t written;

memset(buf, 0, 4096);
fd = open(file_to_overwrite, O_WRONLY);
fstat(fd, &st);

for (pos = 0; pos < st.st_size; pos += written)
    if ((written = write(fd, buf, min(st.st_size - pos, 4096))) <= 0)
        break;

fsync(fd);
close(fd);
```

Option two:

```
int fd = open(file_to_truncate, O_WRONLY);
ftruncate(fd, 0);
fsync(fd);
close(fd);
```

Error handling left as an exercise.

Answer (score 4):

[mmap()](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/munmap.2.html) and memset()

Comment: But don't forget to msync after the memset, unless you munmap or close.