# Filling a 2GiB file with 0s in C

Tags: c

I am about to do some data processing in C, and the processing part is working logically, but I am having a strange file problem. I conveniently have 32-bits of numbers to consider, so I need a file of 32-bits of 0s, and then I will change the 0 to 1 if something exists in a finite field.

My question is: What is the best way to make a file with all "0s" in C?

What I am currently doing, seems to make sense but is not working. I currently am doing the following, and it doesn't stop at the 2.4GiB mark. I have no idea what's wrong or if there's a better way.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef uint8_t u8;
typedef uint32_t u32;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    u32 l_counter32 = 0;
    u8  l_ubyte = 0;
    FILE *f_data; 

    f_data = fopen("file.data", "wb+");
    if (f_data == NULL) {
        printf("file error\n");
        return(0);
    }
    for (l_counter32 = 0; l_counter32 <= 0xfffffffe; l_counter32++) {
        fwrite(&l_ubyte, sizeof(l_ubyte), 1, f_data);   
    }
    fwrite(&l_ubyte, sizeof(l_ubyte), 1, f_data);   //final byte at 0xffffffff
    fclose(f_data);
}
```

I increment my counter in the loop to be 0xFFFFFFFe, so that it doesn't wrap around and run forever..  I haven't waited for it to stop actually, I just keep checking on the disk via ls -alF and when it's larger than 2.4GiB, I stop it.  I checked sizeof(l_ubyte), and it is indeed 8-bits.

I feel that I must be missing some mundane detail.

Comment: Well, to have a file filled with zeros one may use [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), so the whole file will be written with a single `lseek/fseek` and a single `write/fwrite`.

Comment: possible duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392110/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-overwrite-an-entire-file-with-zeros-in-c

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF is equal to 4294967295, which is roughly 4 GB, not 2.

Comment: use lseek for a sparse file: man page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) mentions "These operations allow applications to map holes in a sparsely allocated file."

Comment: Sparse files are not universally supported, and the OP didn't specify which operating system they use.

Comment: @Archimaredes Thank you!  I'm an idiot. :/

Comment: You are comparing signed 32 bit integer to 0xfffffffe which is "-2"

Comment: You're welcome. I added it as an answer too.

Comment: @user4815162342 Even where sparse files are not supported, `ftruncate` does the trick.

Comment: @FUZxxl Again, `ftruncate` is POSIX, not C.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes. In portable C, just use `fseek()` to go one before the desired end-of-file and then write a single 0 byte for the same effect.

Comment: @FUZxxl Sure, as long as the OS supports sparse files, which is neither universal nor mandated by C.

Comment: @user4815162342 This has nothing to do with sparse files (again). If the OS does not support sparse files, it will allocate a sufficiently large file when you do that. If the OS allows you to seek past the end of a file anyway.

Comment: @FUZxxl "If the OS does not support sparse files, it will allocate a sufficiently large file when you do that." Is there a reference to support that statement? At least the C99 `fseek` says nothing of the sort.

Comment: @user4815162342 Follows from the definition of `fseek()` and the definition of sparse file. If that allocation wouldn't happen, the file would be sparse because when you write a byte at a certain offset, it's also there when you read back the file without intermediate changes.

Comment: @FUZxxl Either the seek or the write could fail due to invalid position. I don't think it is a coincidence that POSIX documents seek-past-end+write behavior, and C doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are counting up to `0xffffffff`, which is equal to 4,294,967,295. You want to count up to `0x80000000` for exactly 2 GB of data.

Answer (score 4):

The faster way to create initalize a file with zeroes (alias \0 null bytes) is using `truncate()/ftruncate()`. See [man page here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html)